# JCR session created using ResourceResolver returns null

Tags: aem

I am trying to implement the example

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/querying-experience-manager-data-using1.html

but in the following code

ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
    session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

resourceResolver.adaptTo returns null everytime

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: AEM6 provide the subservices concept to get the session. Here did you find what exactly resolverFactory returns?

Comment: Thanks Vivek.It returns a JCRResource resolver.

Comment: What is the package imported for Session ?

Comment: it imports javax.jcr.Session;

Comment: @user1904 any reason for using getAdministrativeResourceResolver() ? It is deprecated by now. Are you using an old API?

Comment: if you only need an admin session you can start from the SlingRepository and call repository.loginAdministrative(null). If you need the ResourceResolver and are in a request you can get it from there, though it will be with the access right of the initiator of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your resolverFactory is returning an object. If not, session will always be null. If you have not made use of @Reference annotation to get resolverFactory reference, please make use of it and see if it returns the resolverFactory,reference as follows:

@Reference
private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

If your using a HttpSlingServlet , then we can get the session using sling request as shown below.
SlingHttpServletRequest.getResourceResolver() method
For reference you can follow the below api.

https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html

This might be the solution. If it doesn't work, Can you please share the entire code so that it is easy to track the exact reason why it is returning null value.